# Regex Only letters but if the name is composed do not remove it

Tags: regex

I want to delete all numbers, just leave the words but if the word is compound then don't delete it, example:

- Input: `Hola B2B 234234 2.2.2`
- Output: `Hola B2B`

That is, if the number is after the letter and forms a single word then leave it, but if the number begins without a letter then delete it.

I have this but it doesn't work for me https://regexr.com/7dbos

Comment: What flavor/tool are you using?

Comment: What about `2AB`?

Comment: @Nick should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match "words" that start with a digits and are entirely composed of digits and/or dots:

```
(^| )\d[.\d]*\b
```

See [regex live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ZSGSUYgWjAxTOC).

Replace matches with a blank to "delete" them, leaving you with the string you want.

`(^| )` added at the front to enforce a word boundary and consume leading spaces to avoid multiple spaces being left after treating, for example `"Hola B2B 234234 2.2.2 Amigo"` would otherwise leave `"Hola B2B   Amigo"`

See [live demo of the replace executing in python](https://ideone.com/qxup3g).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
\b([A-Za-z]|\d)*[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z]|\d)*\b/g
```

but you haven't specified enough test cases for me to be sure of your intent (e.g. what do you want to happen with underscores? What about non-ASCII letters? & what I've given here allows "2B2B", but I don't know if you want that. Etc.)

Comment: @Gilles Quénot, thank you for the fix, I gather I ran afoul of something where I though I could write in plain text but it was interpreted as markup.

Comment: @Lenin Zapata: If you don't want to allow beginning with a digit, omit the first parenthesized expression.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the example, please consider editing it a bit..

Comment: My answer is still fine for that additional case, which does NOT address the questions of intent I raised. Let me try to spell it out. Are each of the following a match or not:
2B2B
A_25
_25
_A25
É23
EÉ23